# Studio/IDE to write web ui that will run a R script

Tags: r, user-interface, web

I have an R script that I wish to run through an apache server. I would like to create a simple web interface that will accept certain parameters, call the R script, and return the results as a page.

Is there a studio (like VS) that will simplify this process? I have never written GUI in R before, or web gui for that matter, so starting from scratch will be a pain.

Thanks in advance,
Prot

Comment: Do you have to use Apache?  Shiny is probably the easiest way of creating simple web apps.  http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/  On the other hand, if you need to use certain technologies to integrate with other applications, then say so.

Comment: We have an existing webserver that's used for other projects in department, and the IT staff that run the servers don't like doing new things, so I think it's gonna have to be Apache. Unless you can seamlessly run Shiny + Apache together without too much fuss.

Comment: So what technology (other than Apache) do the other projects use for creating their web apps?  That simplifies your problem to "how do I call R from that technology?".

Comment: Let's assume (I'll check with the IT guys later), that it's only Apache and nothing else. Does Shiny allow easy VS style GUI creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 4 options for creating a web app with R.  Choose your IDE after you've picked your technology.

**Shiny**

As I mentioned in the comments, the easiest way to create simple web apps is do use [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/).  For your particular requirements, it may not be appropriate since it uses [Shiny Server](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server) rather than Apache.  (It also currently has some issues with Internet Explorer due to its use of Twitter Bootstrap.)

**Rook**

The [Rook package](http://anythingbutrbitrary.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-simple-web-application-using-rook.html) is perhaps the next simplest option, and you can use `RApache` as your web server.  (I haven't used it; I don't know whether `RApache` allows links to an existing Apache web server, or whether it has its own.)

**gWidgets**

The `gWidgets` framework let's you write code that can be run using R's tcltk, GTK and qt GUI tollkits as well as a web app (again based in `RApache`).  Use this is you might want a dekstop version as well as the web app.  See John Verzani's [comparison of gWidgetsWWW2 and Shiny](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/11/comparing-shiny-with-gwidgetswww2-rapache/).

**Calling R from some other tech**

You can call R in batch mode from more or less any other technology.  So create your web app with whatever tools your colleagues are using, and then call R from that.  (Some technologies have nicer integration with R than mere batch files.  But worry about the best way to communicate once you know what that technology is.)